# Execute a command as another user, without root

Tags: linux, bash

On my system, there are 2 users: david and wall

I want to allow david to run wall's script, with password prompt, to allow david to type wall's password, but without root privilege. The script must not be run as root.

David know the password of wall.

Here is the permission of the wall script. Only wall can read and execute it.

```
ls -l '/home/david/wall_script.sh' 
-rwxr-x--x 1 wall wall 37 juin   4 08:27 /home/david/wall_script.sh
```

The following command don't work because permissions

```
$ sudo -u wall '/home/david/wall_script.sh' 
sudo: unable to execute /home/david/wall_script.sh: Permission denied
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User **wall** usually do not have access to user **david**  home directory. Put the script in some other space and the try again.

Comment: Failed. Same issue about permissions

Comment: @NicolasSmith, check my edited answer

Comment: You right, I moved the script in /opt and success

Comment: Also: When using `sudo`, then wall will have to type in wall's password; giving out david's password to wall is useless, as wall could simply log in as david then.